# Can't limit for each loop with Google Places api

Tags: java, android, foreach

I'm just trying to just get 5 results for the Google Places api, this is bringing out all the results it can found, but I just want the first 5 , and it seems I can't even change anything from that for. I tried first adding a counter before the loop and then increment that by one until it gets to 5 but I think it's not working properly.

Any ideas?

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {


                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) //I need to limit this to only 5 results {
...
```

Comment: change for each loop to a normal one ..

Comment: i cant do that since im working with PlaceLikelihoodBuffer

Comment: so what ? you can do somthing like  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood =likelyPlaces.get(i); }

Comment: well lets end it you got your answer .. have a happy coding (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter and a break when the counter reaches 5;

```
counter=0;
for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces){
    if(counter==5){
        break;
    }
    counter+=1;
    //do your stuff here with the 5 locations
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, i did the same thing before the question with just if(limit<=5) but without the break, now is working fine like it should, thanks